# is there any other method for pushing code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, github

I'm beginner to coding and currently using vs code so to pushing the codes on Github I give the command but it was not giving the output as it was desired as I initially push Code in Github by vs code the authentication was provided by Git not by vs code And it is showing everything is alright in terminal but when I check[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YtMU.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w69qR.png) Github I didn't find any updated code which I have posted so please help me for that.

i have mentioned above that wwhat i have tried .[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHWr8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRARk.png)
and was expecting output as shown here in images.

Comment: Can you provide the result of `git log --oneline` running in your terminal in vscode? It seems to me that everything is fine, only `git push` does not show you the history of local repository, `git log` does. `git push` will only send the data to remote and show you some basic stuff, not the history like in github though, that comes from `git log`.

Answer (score 2):

You are created demo folder inside demo folder in 2 files one is html and second is readme file.
follow the below step for pushing code

```
cd demo
ls -- show folder demo
cd demo
ls -- show all files 

after

git init
git add .
git commit -m 'message'
git add remote origin `url`
git push origin main
```